# My if and else statement always think it's -and

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selector on my page that has -and or -or. I'd like to change the content of a `div` depending on what users choose with -And or -Or.

My if and else statements aren't working right now, well it's almost working it just always add -And. It looks as if it always see's -And?

First time I'm trying to use an if and else statement and I think I made mistake.

```
<script>
function Andor' + count + '(selTag) {  
  var x = selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;  
  if (x = '-and'){ 
    document.getElementById("and-or-' + count + '").innerHTML = " " + x + " ";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("and-or-' + count + '").innerHTML = " " + x + " (";
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: x == '-and' its two equal signs

Comment: There are two ways to equate in JS.  `==` and `===`.  

The `==` operator compares for equality while also doing type conversions, as applicable. On the other hand,  `===` will avoid type conversions, 

e.g.

    1===1 //true
    
    1==1 //true
    
    1===2 // false
    1==2 // false
    "1"===1 // false
    "1"==1 //true

Answer (score 1):

You use one `=`, which is 'assign'. You want `===` (or `==`) for 'equals'.

You do the same as: `var example = 'foo';`. You set the value to a string ('-and'), which always results in true, which makes it look like it's true. 
What you want is `example=='foo'` to check if the content of `example` equals 'foo'.

Suggested reading material: https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a

Comment: I thought that = was 'equals', it work's now so easy! Thank you. I searched for material on Google but nothing had something like that. Thank you again.

Comment: @baswijdenesdotcom It depends on the language, most C style languages use `==` for comparisons.

Comment: I never work with other languages then PowerShell. This is completely new for me.

Comment: @baswijdenesdotcom then I recommend you javascript.info great site to learn a lot about javascript.